# Throw a custom exception in optional in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have this piece of code where I want to throw an Exception wether the resource is not found

```
Menu menu = menuService.findById(addMenuAmount.getMenuId())
                    .orElseThrow(com.tdk.web.exception.ResourceNotFoundException(“menu "  + 
                            addMenuAmount.getMenuId() + " not found "));
```

but I got a compilation Error:

```
com.tdk.web.exception cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: `Optional.orElseThrow` takes a `Supplier` that supplies/creates the exception. You appear to be passing the exception directly.

Comment: `orElseThrow` expects a `Supplier` as its only parameter. You can use a lambda expression to return your exception which is to be thrown. `Supplier`'s only method accepts no argument and in this case expects you to return an `Exception` or a subclass. `() -> new YourException()` would suffice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this and make sure that `com.tdk.web.exception.ResourceNotFoundException` is accesible

```
Menu menu = menuService.findById(addMenuAmount.getMenuId())
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new com.tdk.web.exception.ResourceNotFoundException("menu "  + 
                            addMenuAmount.getMenuId() + " not found "));
```

Note the lambda `() ->` and quotes `"menu "`.